# Comparing two lists their values and return the values when they are equal

Tags: c#, list, compare

Ok, so i have these three lists.

```
List<Request> requests = db.GetRequests();
List<Request> acceptedRequestsByQuality = new List<Request>();
Volunteer.Qualities;
```

I want to compare the volunteers' qualities and the qualities that are given in the request objects in the requests list. When the volunteer qualitylist contains all quality's that are in request.qualities i want to add these requests to the acceptedRequestsByQuality List and return them.

I have the following code, but i cant seem to get it to work, i dont know what to put in the foreach :S

```
public List<Request> GetRequestForUser(Account account)
{
    var hasall = true;
    bool accepted = false;
    List<Request> requests = db.GetRequests();
    List<Request> acceptedRequestsByQuality = new List<Request>();
    String type = account.GetType().ToString();
    switch (type)
    {
        //Creates a new tab for all tabs that the account needs.
        case "S21M_B_Participation_Forms.Volunteer":
            Volunteer volunteer = (Volunteer) account;
            foreach(Request request in requests)
            {
                var b = volunteer.Qualities.Intersect(request.Qualities);
            }
            break;
    }

    return acceptedRequestsByQuality;
}
```

Comment: Your `switch` could just be an `if` as in `if(type == "S21M_B_Participation_Forms.Volunteer")`  unless you have a lot more cases you are not showing.

Comment: Also you can check the type directly, as in.. if (account is Volunteer) .. or even better use 'as'  to avoid the cast later on: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488006.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want.

```
foreach(Request request in requests)
{
    if(!request.Qualities.Except(volunteer.Qualities).Any())
        acceptedRequestsByQuality.Add(request)
}
```

This assumes that the type of the items in `Qualities` correctly overrides the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods so that comparing them will actually work.

Comment: This one looks better.. I must say double negatives and Any() makes you dizzy a little though :)

Comment: @MaxwellTroyMiltonKing An alternative would be to use `.Count() == 0`, but `Any` avoids potentially iterating the entire sequence.

Comment: Could you maybe use .All() and get rid of the not.. might still look a little confusing though.. No, no, I like your answer.

Comment: @MaxwellTroyMiltonKing If you do `Intersect` instead you have to compare the `Count` of the result with the `Count` of `request.Qualities`.  I cannot really think of a way that would involve using `All`.

Comment: Thank you for ur answer, unfortunately its still not working. Its not getting into the for loop. Let me explain it again: when the volunteer has the qualities needed for the request, it should add that request to the acceptedrequestbyquality<List>

Comment: @J.Verlaek Is your `account` of the type you are checking?

Comment: Yes, it should be a volunteer. The qualities are in the list, but when i use your method, it never goes into the if statement.

Comment: @J.Verlaek Is your `Qualitiy` class (or whatever is in the `Qualities` collections) setup to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` so the comparisons will be value based instead of reference based?

Comment: I dont think so, could u give me some information on how to set that up? Sorry if im asking too much, im still a student and this is giving me a headache :S

Comment: @J.Verlaek Here's a set of guidelines for overriding `Equals`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx  If you have a specific question about it I recommend asking a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You are not populating your new list. Add your findings to it:

```
var b = volunteer.Qualities.Except(request.Qualities);
if (b.Count() == 0)   
   acceptedRequestsByQuality.Add(request);
```

Edit:

Thanks to juharr for pointing out the logic error. See his answer for a tidier solution (and possibly with the correct logic).

Comment: Nope, `acceptedRequestsByQuality` is a `List<Request>()` and `b` is `IEnumerable<Quality>`

Comment: If that doesn't work you may need a custom equality comparer: "The default equality comparer, Default, is used to compare values of the types that implement the IEqualityComparer<T> generic interface. To compare a custom data type, you need to implement this interface and provide your own GetHashCode and Equals methods for the type." -https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: `b` is just the ones that match.  The OP stated that they only want to add if all the `request.Qualities` are in `volunteer.Qualities`.  So just checking `b.Count() > 0` isn't going to work.

Comment: Oh OK. I was assuming he was on the right track with the logic.. I'll add a note to my answer